# Is it possible to fire and forget a long-running SQL statement (on SQL Server 2005+) from a .net thread?

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-applications, garbage-collection, connection-pooling

I am firing off a very long running query via BeginExecuteNonQuery.

I want to close my connection and allow this query to continue its work on the server (I will check on the results later via a new connection/thread).

However, it seems that whenever my connection is garbage collected (even if I didn't specifically close it), the server-side process is terminated.

I am using connection pooling and suspect this could be the problem - can anyone suggest a solution for me?

Thanks!

**Edit**:
Someone mentioned this in a comment (and then deleted the comment?!)
http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/

It is quite useful, but required that I create a service, queue and a couple of stored procs, which I don't really want to do.

Also, I cannot guaranteed the Sql Agent Service being active so cannot be create jobs to run the SQL, unfortunately.

Comment: Closing the connection will abort whatever BeginExecuteNonQuery is doing. Is there a reason you want to close it?

Comment: What if you execute the query on a different thread?

Comment: @AlexK. Yes there are several reasons, which I don't really want to go into as it will take some time! It's best to assume that I have no choice about closing/disposing my connection and that I want to leave some long-running SQL active on the server.

Comment: @KaiHartmann - I don't have the choice about keeping any .net resources running. No threads, no connections.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean - Hmm - I came across this article whilst searching for an answer to this problem - it seems remarkably complicated! Also, I'm rather restricted on what I can create on the SQL Server, so creating a Queue, Service and couple of Stored Procs is far from ideal. Thanks though!

Comment: Its possible & not all that difficult, essentially all you need to do is to script a job which contains your long running procedure which is scheduled to run one or two minutes in the future. Once you've created the job you can close the connection & let sql server agent do the work for you

Comment: @Johnv2020 - thanks.... did I mention that I can't rely on Sql Server Agent? Nope, I didn't - sorry!!! But, I can't rely on Sql Server Agent. So, no jobs, I'm afraid.

Comment: Just a Guess, but could you use BCP and shell out to it?

Answer (score 0):

Close the connection inside of the callback that you register with `BeginExecuteNonQuery`. As a side-effect this will keep the `SqlConnection` object alive. Also you need to ensure disposal anyway, even for a long-running statement.